Packages not being installed during docker build (ifcopneshell, bpy)
I am trying a build a docker image, but I am running into the package installation issue. When I run docker build -t bsn-server .,
I get the following error:
21.75 Collecting idna==3.7
21.78   Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
21.81      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 66.8/66.8 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
21.92 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ifcopenshell==0.7.0.240521 (from versions: none)
21.92 ERROR: No matching distribution found for ifcopenshell==0.7.0.240521
22.09 
22.09 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 24.2
22.09 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  11 |     # Install Python dependencies
  12 | >>> RUN apt-get update && \
  13 | >>>     apt-get install -y gcc build-essential && \
  14 | >>>     pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
  15 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y gcc build-essential &&     pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

The package installs when I install it locally using pip install ifcopenshell==0.7.0.240521. I am not sure why it is not being installed during the docker build
The following are the relevant packages from my requirements.txt
ifcopenshell==0.7.0.240521
bpy=4.0.0

The following is the docker file:
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the app runs on
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variable
ENV UVICORN_APP=server:combined_asgi_app
ENV UVICORN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV UVICORN_PORT=8000
ENV UVICORN_RELOAD=True

# Run the application
CMD ["uvicorn", "server:combined_asgi_app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]


